# Serach function Array to string conversion error in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I can't figure out how to make my search function work. I understand why i get the `Array to string conversion`  error,but i dont know how to fix it. Of course i have tried to find something similar, but no such luck(Probably used the wrong key words)

Controller Code

```
  $materials = DB::table('materials')
        ->orderBy("id","asc")
        ->paginate(20);

          foreach ($materials as $key=>$material)
          {
              $alternatives = DB::table('alternatives')
                ->select('alternatives')
                ->where('material_id', $material->id)
                ->get();

              $links = DB::table('alternatives')
                ->select('links')
                ->where('material_id', $material->id)
                ->get();

              $materials[$key]->alternatives = $alternatives;
              $materials[$key]->links = $links;

          }
          $materials->where([['reference', '!=', Null],
                    [function ($query) use ($request)
                    {
                        if(($search_reference = $request->search_reference))
                        {
                            $query->orWhere('reference','LIKE','%' . $search_reference . '%')
                            ->orWhere('description','LIKE','%' . $search_reference . '%')
                            ->orWhere('scanner_code','LIKE','%' . $search_reference . '%')
                            //->orWhere('alternatives','LIKE','%' . $search_reference . '%')
                            ->orWhere([['alternatives', '!=', Null],
                                      [function ($query) use ($request)
                                      {
                                          if(($search_reference = $request->search_reference))
                                          {
                                            $query->orWhere('alternatives','LIKE','%' . $search_reference . '%');
                                          }
                                      }]
                                    ])
                            ->get();
                        }
                    }]  // Error gets shown here!
                  ])
              ->orderBy("id","asc")
              ->paginate(20);

        return view('materials.index', ['materials' => $materials]);
```

I would appreciate if somebody could help me.

Comment: Which line are you getting that error on?

Comment: On line 100 in my code, which is " }] " so doesn't really help :D

Comment: Neither does what you just told us help, because `}]` occurs multiple times in your code.

Comment: Edited the code to show the position where it happens.

Comment: You're passing multiple arrays into your orWhere clauses, two with closures. You can separate all of them out, and also use `orWhereNotNull` for the parts that need it. Though really, the `orWhereNotNull` is going to conflict with `alternatives like %string%`, meaning that it's going to pull up everything that's not null anyway. Decide which you need

Answer (score 0):

```
                             ])
                            ->get();
                        }
                    }]
```

remove this `get()`. sub-queries doesn't accept collection. they accepts only queries. when you use `get()`, it turns to a collection.